# Android shell commands

Tags: java, android, facebook, shell

When I SSH into my android phone and run the command "ps | grep facebook" I get the proper output...

```
23394 app_25     0:26 com.facebook.katana
23432 app_25     0:02 com.facebook.katana:providers
25073 root       0:00 grep facebook
```

However if I run the same command through Java using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps | grep facebook"); I end up getting...

```
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAMEapp_25    23394 111   169388 53420 ffffffff 00000000 S com.facebook.katana
```

What I am looking for specifically is the time just to the left of com.facebook.katana

Here is the code I am using...

```
private String getResultFromCommandLine(String command)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String temp;

    try
    {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        while ((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(temp);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) { }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Does anyone know why I am not getting the same output?

Comment: I found the source of the problem, there are 2 different ps's on my phone and I was able to get the information I needed by calling it like "ps -x | frep facebook"

Comment: Why don't you post this as the answer?